# Maven dependancy with spring boot and Junit

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, junit

I'm working on a project based on spring-boot 1.2.5.

When I execute my tests with the maven install script, they are passed with sucess.
But when i try to execute my tests with **JUnit** in eclipse, i have the following issue:

> java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.hamcrest.Matchers"'s signer
>   information does not match signer information of other classes in the
>   same package  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:895)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:665)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:758)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   net.aptea.sba.tests.controllers.TestClientController.listClient(TestClientController.java:24)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

I think it's a problem of dependancy inside spring boot framework:

[Dependancy hirarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKvLK.png)

So i added this following lines in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

mvn dependency:tree result:

```
[INFO] net.aptea.sba:sba-web:war:0
[INFO] +- net.aptea.sba:sba-metier-dao:jar:0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.7.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.9.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4-1202-jdbc42:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:1.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:1.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:jempbox:jar:1.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:138:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:138:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.ews-java-api:ews-java-api:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:jar:2.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring3:jar:2.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:config-types:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:core:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-config:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.jvnet:tiger-types:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:bean-validator:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-runlevel:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:class-model:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:asm-all-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:spring-bridge:jar:2.4.0-b06:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.14:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.23:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.23:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.23:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.23:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO] \- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO]    +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- net.minidev:asm:jar:1.0:test
[INFO]    |     \- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:test
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.927 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-29T17:46:31+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/275M
[INFO] -----------------------------
```

But i'm not able to solve this issue.

Do you have an idea of how to solve this problem ?
Thank you for your advises.

Ravi N.

Comment: Don't add those dependencies use the `spring-boot-starter-test` instead of individual jars.

Comment: I'm already using spring-boot-starter-test but, as you can see in my screen shot (Dependancy hirarchy), there is a lot of conflict that's why i added those dependancies.

Comment: If you have conflicts you are doing things you shouldn't be doing in the first place. Also your screenshot doesn't tell me anything only that you use that starter. If you have conflicts you aren't using spring boot properly to manage  your dependencies. Post your actual pom and/r the output of `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: I have posted the mvn dependency:tree result. If you see something wrong please tell me. Thank you a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

duffymo was partialy right, it's a problem with Eclipse and his integrated JUnit.

To solve my problem, I did this:

1 - Download the latest hamcrest-all jar from here : https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/hamcrest/

2- Go on the eclipse installation folder: eclipse/plugin/ and find the org.hamcrest...jar

3- make a backup of the step 2 jar and replace it by the step 1 jar (rename it same as the jar step 2).

4- restart eclipse

After that, my issue was solved.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you pom.xml is incorrect.  I have this in mine:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

JUnit has a dependency on hamcrest-core, but its pom.xml has Maven bring it in without you having to explicitly ask for it in yours.

It might be that Eclipse has a built-in JUnit that conflicts with the version in your pom.xml.  I'd recommend a better IDE - use IntelliJ from JetBrains.

Comment: In my case i try to exclude the "hamcrest-core" dependancy from Junit because this JAR is already include in spring-boot-starter-test (as you can see in my screen shot Dependancy hirarchy).

Comment: I'm using all those JARs too, and I can run tests without exclusions or issues in both Maven and IntelliJ.

Comment: I will try with IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

The designated answer is misleading, and not the right thing to do at all. All I did was go into Project Properties and remove JUnit from the Java Build Path. Eclipse had automagically added it at some point when I was running tests directly, rather than from maven.